# CF/CloudFoundry "/home/vcap/app" not found?

Tags: cloud-foundry, tanzu-application-service

I am pushing my app to Cloud Foundry. When it runs it creates a folder and saves a file to where it is running (*AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory*).

My apps runs perfectly locally, but in Tanzu when it tries to acces the file it saved I get this error:

> Message":"An error occurred trying to start process '/home/vcap/app/fileName' with working directory '/home/vcap/app'. No such file or directory"

Any ideas?

Comment: I understand you have a custom app that tries to access its own container filesystem read/write. But read/write is not executing, so it’s strange that it says “trying to start process”. What exact operations are you performing in order to “access” this file?